# Python Subprocess can not get the output of oracle command "imp"

Tags: python, oracle

For example:

```
import subprocess
p=subprocess.Popen("imp -help",stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
out,err=p.communicate
```

the out is `null`

but other oracle command like "`sqlplus -help`","`rman -help`" works fine

Answer (score 1):

There could be two problems why you are not getting any output in stdout:

1. The process is dumping all it's output to stderr.
2. The system does not know how to execute `"imp -help"`.

The solution for the first problem is easy: capture stderr using the argument `stderr = subprocess.PIPE`.

The solution to the second is also easy, but the explanation is a bit longer: Subprocess does not guess much, it will just try to execute the whole string as one command. That means, in your case, it will try to execute `"imp -help"` as one command. It does not try to execute the command `"imp"` with the argument `"-help"`. You have to explicitly tell subprocess the command and the arguments separately.

From the python [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) on subprocess:

> args should be a string, or a sequence
>   of program arguments. The program to
>   execute is normally the first item in
>   the args sequence or the string if a
>   string is given, ...

That means you have to separate the command and the arguments and pack them together in a sequence. This: `"imp -help"` should look like this: `["imp", "-help"]`. Read the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) on subprocess for more details on the intricacies of spliting the command and arguments.

Here is how the code should look like:

```
import subprocess
p=subprocess.Popen(["imp", "-help"],
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
out,err=p.communicate()
```

Note: you also typed `p.communicate` instead of `p.communicate()`. I assume that was a typo in your question, not in your code.

Comment: and the out is null again,but err has the output.

Comment: by using out,err=p.communicate you don't call commincate you only refereence to it

Comment: @koko if the process just outputs stuff on stderr then stdout will be empty.